# Keep computer awake while R program is running

Tags: windows, r

How do I keep my computer awake while R is running? I have windows 7.

Comment: A strong cup of coffee or some lively conversation.

Comment: This isn't really an R question, is it?

Comment: Seems like a pretty good question to me.

Comment: @eddi for [so]? This seems to be a question about stopping Windows hibernating a computer, which may be on topic for [su], but not here.

Comment: @GavinSimpson yes - there does exist API for keeping windows awake and it's an interesting question how to utilize that from R

Comment: @eddi You are inferring a Question that the OP didn't ask. A better Answer for the OP may involve Control Panel > Power Options so hibernation doesn't happen at all or not for long periods. He may have meant to ask this question, but perhaps wait for them to improve the Question? It has only been put on hold.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I'd phrase it differently - I'm just reading the question with a programming mindset.

Comment: @eddi Even if we assume your interpretation is correct, this is still a terrible question that lacks detail or evidence that the OP has done any research or made any attempts themselves, and should remain on hold unless/until the OP can improve or clarify these issues.

Answer (score 2):

From [this topic](http://www.sevenforums.com/performance-maintenance/185644-how-do-i-prevent-going-sleep-processes-active.html) you can follow a few suggestions. There are some third-party programs
but it seems `powercfg` can do this too.

**See the edit below** (powercfg does not do what is needed here)

Something like `POWERCFG -REQUESTSOVERRIDE PROCESS myprogram.exe Display System` would do the trick.

You need to start `powercdg` in an elevated command prompt. (Click Start/Type cmd/choose with right-click cmd.exe at the top and click "run as administrator". Now you can enter the commands followed by `exit`+<kbd>enter</kbd>

```
powercfg -requestoverride

Code:

  -REQUESTSOVERRIDE
              Sets a Power Request override for a particular Process, Service,
              or Driver. If no parameters are specified, this command displays
              the current list of Power Request Overrides.
              Usage: POWERCFG -REQUESTSOVERRIDE <CALLER_TYPE> <NAME> <REQUEST>
   ....
              Example:
                  POWERCFG -REQUESTSOVERRIDE PROCESS wmplayer.exe Display System
```

**Edit**: Unfortunately `powercfg -requestoverride` does **not** what it needs to do in this case. It overrides the override-setting some programs can set in Windows to prevent sleep. For example myprogram.exe can ask Windows to prevent going to sleep. If you don't want this behavior you, as a user, can use  `powercfg -requestoverride` to override it. (an override for an override :)

For now the best option is [programming this behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373208%28VS.85%29.aspx) in your own program or using a program like [Don't Sleep](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/11/21/dont-sleep-prevent-standby-hibernate-shutdown-in-windows/), [Insomnia](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/09/30/give-your-computer-insomnia-free-tool-and-source-code-to-temporarily-prevent-a-machine-from-going-to-sleep.aspx) or [Caffeine](http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/index.html). But with these programs you need to enable and disable sleep manually. (It does not detect running processes).

(Maybe a hint for a programmer... Oops... I'm a programmer, but don't have the time right now :)